# Views Row Classes Not Appearing

Tags: views

I'm using a view to display articles, I want to see **views row classes** in the code, like this:

```
div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first
```

But for some reason the rendered code is missing these row-specific div wrappers and just shows the nodes like this:

```
div id="node-4" class="node node-article"
```

Even more frustrating, the code in the views PREVIEW shows the desired **views row classes** `div class="views-row views-row-1"` but those div wrappers don't appear in the rendered site code.

On the last site I made, the views-row classes appeared automatically. Now for some reason they're not appearing. I've been frantically googling and pulling my hair out for two days on this so any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: Is this a default Drupal theme ? Can you tell us which theme you're using and provide a views export ?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply tenken... I'm using a contrib theme called CorporateClean

Comment: Not sure how to do a views export

Comment: would seeing the actual website help?

Answer (score 3):

Did you check:

1. Template (*.tpl.php file) override. I am not sure if preview shows template overrides.
2. Template.php for altering hooks
3. Contrib modules for altering hooks

Comment: sorry if I sound like a dummy, but how would I override the .tpl.php file and which one would I override? Thanks for your help majeklch

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of views settings?

Comment: http://kylelewisdesign.com/viewsettings.png

Comment: My guess is, that your problems are because of this: "The selected style or row format does not utilize fields." So Drupal displays node teasers and doesn't add views row classes. Please check your settings in Format box above Fields.

Answer (score 0):

Copy-pasting a core template into my theme helped resolve this issue:

```
cp ../../core/modules/views/templates/views-view-unformatted.html.twig \
  templates/views/views-view-unformatted.html.twig
```